# Injection and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, dependency-injection

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
   void collide(Vehicle v){}
}

class Car extends Vehicle
{
   @Override 
   void collide(Vehicle v){super.collide(v);}
}  

class Truck extends Vehicle
{
   @Override 
   void collide(Vehicle v){super.collide(v);}
}
```

If I do :

```
@Inject   
Vehicle vehicle;
```

1. How does `@Inject` know which one to instantiate ?
2. I think this will throw an `AmbiguousResolutionException`, am I wrong?

I would like to do this to avoid this problem  and also specialize the parameters but it's not allowed, and I understand [why](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267310/overriding-methods-by-passing-as-argument-the-subclass-object-where-the-supertyp).

```
class Car extends Vehicle
{
   @Override 
   void collide(Car v){super.collide(v);}
}  

class Truck extends Vehicle
{
   @Override 
   void collide(Truck v){super.collide(v);}
}
```

3. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. it does not (see 2)
2. you are quite right, it is ambiguos and will throw an exception
3. Basically, you have the following possibilities:

Inject all:

```
@Inject Instance<Vehicle> allVehicles; // see Instance docs on how to work with this
```

Qualify somehow: you write qualifier annotations to go with this, along the lines of:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Small {}
```

...

```
@Small
class Car extends Vehicle { ... }
```

...

```
@Inject @Small Vehicle thisWillBeACar;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By doing that, I need to specify which kind of vehicle I want and I don't know that. You can see my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Second answer to your edited post (as you go into a totally different problem domain here):

For the specialization of parameters, you only have the possibility to parameterize the class itself, along the lines of:

```
abstract class Vehicle<T> {  // T is the "collision partner class"
    abstract void collide(T v);
}

class Car extends Vehicle<Car> {
    @Override 
    void collide(Car v) { ... }
}
```

You can then inject a specialized type:

```
@Inject Vehicle<Car> thisIsACar;
```

Nevertheless, judging from your example, this is probably not what you want ;-)